# What is the meaning of "./" in os.path?

Tags: python, path

I'm trying to search a file in my directory files. I saw an example and couldn't understand:

```
import os
import glob

file_glob = './rpts/folderA/*_fileA.txt'
magic_check = re.compile('[*?[]')
if(magic_check.search(file_glob))
    file_list = glob.glob(os.path.expanduser(file_glob))
```

What does the `./` part mean? I understand that `../` is switch to previous dir.

What I think it does:

1. expand the wild card to get a list of files that matches the regex
2. The files are stored in a list called `file_list`
3. Magic check regex, `[*?[]`: What is the `[` inside `[ ]` for?

Comment: `"./"` is verbose to say "here"- a relative path, instead of trying to get a full, absolute path (i.e. "./files" instead of "C://python35/program/files")

Comment: This has nothing to do with Python, really. `.` is the current working directory; you can try it in your shell too.

Comment: Note that `../` is 'the parent directory'; it is not really the 'previous directory'.

Comment: Yeah, notice how that's inside of a string, not an actual Python command.  Similarly, '~/' references your home directory.  There are a number of bash cheatsheets out there if you want to see more.

Comment: What about number 3 of the question?

Comment: @MuhammadBinladen please split your question if you have sevaral points. Remember, this is not a forum, this is a collaborative knowledge database.

Comment: @MuhammadBinladen: stick to **one** issue per post please. New questions go to new posts.

Answer (score 1):

As Martijn said, this is UNIX shell notation for the current location (**cwd** or **pwd**).  The reason it's in the command is to be more robust.  If the user's environment doesn't have "./" in the search path ($PATH variable), then the shell won't find the file **rpts/folderA/*_fileA.txt**.  With "./" at the front, this script is independent of **$PATH**.